# Can I send commands to JavaScript via URL?

Tags: javascript, ios, automation, workflow

I'm trying to create and iOS Workflow to automatically search the Mexican Post Office website to track my shipment

I've found the JavaScript URL, now I would like to know if it's possible to send the command though the URL for it to be automatically filled with the tracking number and hit search (Buscar)

The URL is:
http://www.correosdemexico.gob.mx/lservicios/Seguimientopieza/Seguimiento.aspx

Thanks!!

Comment: What is a "JavaScript URL"?

Comment: Sorry, I clearly am no expert haha I meant the URL where just the search field and results is shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the URL in a WKWebView. After webpage is loaded you can execute your custom JavaScript by the [evaluateJavascript](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) method. Your JavaScript should insert your tracking number + press the search button.

If you don't want to use the WKWebView approach, you could also simulate the post request of the form.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Seguimiento.aspx" id="form1">
```

Therefore you have to create a NS(Mutable)URLRequest object and set all the necessary fields from the html form with your data. Your target URL will be **Seguimiento.aspx**. The response is the HTML of that page you will see after pressing the "search" button.